# Need C++ constructor/destructor on stack in PHP

Tags: php, locking

In my function which has many exit points, I want to lock tables on entry but unlock automatically all tables upon exit of this function whether by exception, return etc.

In C++ I'd create lock tables in a class constructor and unlock tables in destructor and simply create the class on function entry on stack which will automatically be unwinded(destructed) on function exit.

So in C++:

```
struct locktables{

locktables()
{
//lock them all
}
~locktables()
{
//unlock them all
}

};


void process_function()
{
locktables _l_dddsdsdsa;

//logic goes here


}
```

I know that the classes are created as references and not on the stack.

How to do it in PHP?

Comment: You could simulate the same using objects with con/destructors in PHP, but maybe it's a better choice to structure the application in a way that locking is unnecessary to begin with? Or if you're locking, simply make the function call order in a way that ensures that all tables are unlocked at the end of the script?

Comment: But is the guaranteed that class destructor will be called immediately after function exit in PHP just like the stack variables which are immediately destroyed on stack unwinding. I'm working on Drupal CMS which itself uses many other tables. If I don't unlock my tables on function exit then I'm getting error since Drupal will also be using some other tables.

Comment: @Aga: No, that's not guaranteed. Destructors will be called at the end of the script at least, otherwise when garbage collection kicks in. So this depends a bit how long your script runs and how much you want to lock.

Comment: function process_function2(){ /*lock all*/process_function(); /*unlock all*/}                                                          Looks like this will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Why not encapsulate the function call?

```
function doFooWithLock()
{
    lock();
    try
    {
        $return = doFoo();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
       // no idea for what you need to catch.
       unlock();
       throw $e; # re-throw
    }
    unlock();
    return $return;
}

function doFoo()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: No..but a return statement will skip catch block and the subsequent lines.

Comment: That's why it's on the last line in `doFooWithLock()`.